# SQL State change identifier

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

i have a very unusual type of question
I need to compare state change factor between two columns
Column 1

There are values reported from a device in 1 and 0 (1 means active and 0 means not active).

Column 1 reports repetitive values which means there are values being reported every minute Column 1 reports value even if there is no change for eg : at 9am Column 1 gets a value 1 and it adds that to the entry

At 9:02 there is a value of 1 again and it again adds that entry in the column 1.

At 9:03 value is 0 it adds the entry.

At 9:04 the value is 0 again it again logs that entry

Column 1

```
9:00AM    -    1
9:02AM    -    1
9:03AM    -    0
9:04AM    -    1
9:05AM    -    1  
9:06AM    -    0
```

on the other hand Column 2 only reports the values when its not matching the previous value

Column 2

```
9:00AM - 1
9:03AM - 0
9:04AM - 1
9:06AM - 0
```

I am looking to see if the state change factor is equal between column 1 and 2 means if number of times the value changed in column 1 is equal to number of times the values changed in Column 2
For eg : in Column 1 number of times the values changed are 2 which is same as column 1. But the entry's in column 1 are 6 and entry's in column 2 are 4. so i am looking to get result which is irrespective of entry's and only based on the number of times values changed

and looking to get this in python or SQL
Please if any one can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(col2) over (order by col1) as prev_col2
      from t
     ) t
where col2 is distinct from prev_c9l2
```